# Conjecture that relates the set of primes to inequalities

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, combinatorial-number-theory

The following conjecture which I posed has been verified for all $n<10000$ , my question is to find a proof or a disproof of it. The conjecture is as follows:
Consider for all $n \in \mathbb N$ , 
$$
a(n)=\binom{\operatorname{prime}[n+1]}{\operatorname{prime}[n]}
$$ and 
$$ 
b(n)=\frac{\operatorname{prime}[n]^{\operatorname{prime}[n+1]}}{\operatorname{prime}[n+1]^{\operatorname{prime}[n]}},
$$
where $\operatorname{prime}[m]$ is the $m$-th prime number); then for all $n \in \Bbb N$, 
$$
a(n+1)>a(n)\:\text{ if and only if }\:b(n+1)>b(n).
$$

*Example*: take $n=4$ ,$\operatorname{prime}[4]=7$ and $\operatorname{prime}[5]=11$ and $\operatorname{prime}[6]=13$. Then 
$$
\binom{13}{11} < \binom{11}{7}\:\text{ and also }\:\frac{11^{13}}{13^{11}} < \frac{7^{11}}{{11^7}}
$$
*A further example* that shows that the conjecture is not trivial: in some cases among composite numbers the comparison test fails, for example take the numbers $35$ , $60$ , $78$ , we can notice that 
$$
\binom{78}{60}>\binom{60}{35}\:\text{ but }\:\frac{60^{78}}{78^{60}}<\frac{35^{60}}{60^{35}}.
$$
Thank you.

Comment: To reformulate the conjecture, $${p_{n+2}\choose p_{n+1}}>{p_{n+1}\choose p_{n}} \iff p_{n+1}^{p_{n+2}}/p_{n+2}^{p_{n+1}} >p_{n}^{p_{n+1}}/p_{n+1}^{p_n}$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen you are right , that is what I meant . but the problem I am weak at technical writing . I will do the editing as soon as possible .

Comment: Looking at your composite counter example I suspect this holds whenever the ratio between consecutive numbers isn't too big. IIRC it is known that $p_{n+1}< 2p_n$ so it might be true your inequalities imply each other for any three $a <b<  c$ as long as $b < 1.5a$ and $c < 1.5b$ or something like that.